# Is it possible to install Office 365 (2013) on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet?

Tags: windows, wine, virtualization, 15.04, microsoft-office

I would like to install Office 2015/365 on Ubuntu 15.04. I tried to install Office using Wine, but that did not work. Please note that I do not want virtualisation unless it has a [Winconn](http://stanev.org/winconn/)-like behaviour, where application windows are treated like regular Ubuntu application windows by the system.

Comment: the  web-apps work well, and you can easily add windowed shortcuts from chrome http://i.stack.imgur.com/ER3rq.png

Comment: The web apps have limited functionality.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they have near full functionality if you have the license code. Have you tried kingsoft?

Comment: @mchid No they have very limited functionality compared to the full programs, I have access to the full online suite through my job and it is not enough to edit even relatively simple documents properly.

Comment: @crobar Lately, I've been using google docs instead and it works way better than 365 online and does everything I need, exports and or saves the file in almost any available format including pdf, doc, docx, and all sorts of other stuff without freezing up and lagging as 365 online does for me sometimes even with full license that I get from school. No license needed for google docs either, just a google account.

Comment: @mchid I'll certainly give google docs a go then.

Comment: @crobar Don't get me wrong, I've tried my best to give Microsoft the chance here and they seem to be holding out so use whatever works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my experience, the best way to use Office in Ubuntu is by just installing VirtualBox and make a new Windows virtual machine and install Office on it. From there, you have several options to integrate the Office apps more tightly in Ubuntu.

My favorite way is configure it using this solution: `*snip*` *Unfortunately the user deleted the original video :(*

Basically what you do is start Windows "headless" (that is, without a visible window) and then using an RDP client you can start all the Office apps. You can even create nice launchers for them in Ubuntu.

Comment: This method seems to require a disk to install the applications. All I have is a download from the Office website.

Comment: Well yeah, you do need to have a working Windows virtualBox machine.. but really, it's the closest you will get to run Office on Ubuntu..

Comment: Wht I meant in my last comment is that I have only a Microsoft Office download from the Office website, not a disk (Office 365).

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I'm right, you have downloaded an installer for Office, right? You can just install that too within your VirtualBox machine without a problem :) Sorry for late reaction by the way...

Comment: This question is a bit old, but it should be noted that you will need an Ultimate, Enterprise, or Server version of Windows installed in your VM in order to start a remote app session from Ubuntu to your MS Office applications.  Depending on your version of xfreerdp, you may also need to compile the latest build from github.  Neither of these stipulations apply to a full remote desktop session, only for remote app sessions.

Comment: The YouTube video is unavailable. Can anyone link to the instructions please?

Comment: @Gladen the link does not work.

Comment: @wmlynarski It seems that the user removed the origional video and can't find another one explaining the steps... :(

Answer (score 0):

No , Office 2013/365 won't work with lastest wine although the Office installer is begining to work with lastest wine git code.

The best option for you is to use Win7/virtualbox in seamless mode.